# Neo4j query to bring two entities and how they are connected

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j node called entity which can be connected to other entities. I want to write a cypher query where I specify a list of entity ids and it brings me back those entities and how they are connected.

For example:

[image]

So if I specify Entity A and Entity B ids, it should bring me all other entities including mutual relationships (c-d) and interconnecting entity E.

Could someone help me with the cypher query?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `idList` is an input parameter that defines a list of neo4j ids for entities you want to see in the result, this should return what you need:

```
MATCH (a:Entity)-[r:RELATED_TO]->(b:Entity)
WHERE id(a) IN $idList AND id(b) IN $idList
RETURN a, r, b
```

Note that isolated nodes will not be shown in the result. If you want to inlculde those too, you can do this instead:

```
MATCH (a:Entity),(b:Entity)
WHERE id(a) IN $idList AND id(b) IN $idList
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r:RELATED_TO]->(b)
RETURN a, r, b
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately the first one does not return any records and the second one complains that "This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns."  For the idlist, I want to just provide A, B and I want all other other related nodes to be returned.

Comment: do you set the value of $idList? In your question you said that you want to provide "a list of entity ids" and that's why in my answer, the queries need a list of ids defined in $idList. Now when you say you "want to just provide A, B", how do you do that? do you have their neo4j ids, or a value for their properties? 
By the way, that complaint is just a warning. if you define $idList, it should work.